# Using try/except then throw a method inside a class

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling, robotframework

I have this code below, I want to catch exception for method `click_on_element` inside class `WebInterface` by a method `capture_page_screenshot` also inside that class. I've used decorator `catch_exception` but it didn't work.

Please show me how to complete this!

the first: Traceback was: `self` is not defined.

After fixing code by Timus's help: I got the second traceback:During....
I mean it always shows the traceback message when I `raise Exception` [image]

```
def catch_exception(f):
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def func(*args, **kwargs):
        try:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            WebInterface.capture_page_screenshot(self)
            raise Exception(traceback._context_message)
    return func

class WebInterface(object): 
    
    implicitly_timeout = 15
    page_load_timeout = 30
    set_driver_path = False

    def __init__(self, name = None):
        if not self.set_driver_path:
            env_path = env.get_env_var("PATH")
            env_path = ";".join([env_path, Utils.client_driver_path])
            env.set_env_var("PATH", env_path)
            self.set_driver_path = True
        self.screenshot_dir = None
        self.driver = SeleniumLibrary(self.page_load_timeout, self.implicitly_timeout,"")
        
  
    def capture_page_screenshot(self, file_name = None):
        file_name = str(file_name)
        if not self.screenshot_dir:
            self.screenshot_dir = os.path.join(Utils.get_output_dir(), "page_screenshot")
        Utils.create_directory_if_not_exist(self.screenshot_dir)
        _output = self.screenshot_dir
        if not file_name:
            file_name = self.driver.__hash__()
        _output = os.path.join(_output, file_name)
        if not _output.endswith(".png"):
            _output += ".png"
        image_path = self.driver.capture_page_screenshot(_output)
        Utils.add_file_to_report(image_path, file_name)
        return image_path
        
  
    @catch_exception
    def click_on_element(self, locator):
        _locator = Utils.get_values_if_be_a_keyword(locator)
        self.driver.find_element(_locator).click()
```

Comment: Can you [edit] this to describe how it didn't work. A big part of troubleshooting is being able to understand how things deviated from the expected.

Comment: @sphennings: ok I edited description.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: @BryanOakley: ok I will add a picture full traceback. It showed the self is not defined because I call a method inside a class that my method is outside

Comment: Please don't add a picture of the traceback. Take the time to copy and paste it into your question. Images of code and errors aren't searchable, and the visually impaired can't see them at all.

Comment: @BryanOakley: Thank for your notification, I will fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: Replace `WebInterface.capture_page_screenshot(self)` with `args[0].capture_page_screenshot()` in the defintion of `catch_exception`.

The function in the decorator definition knows nothing about `self`: It's not defined inside the class definition and the arguments given to it are only `args` (a list) and `kwargs` (a dictionary):

```
def func(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

When you use the decorator inside the class definition the first element of `args` (`args[0]`) is `self`, because its the first argument given to `click_on_element`.

Comment: Im trying this. Thank you in advance, It throw some tracebacks and Im fixing it.

Comment: It's worked. Many thanks. Could you show me why we write args[0] ?

Comment: One more trouble, Why it cant raise the exception.. Please see my 1st pic added recently

Comment: @Scorpisces Okay, could you try `args[0].capture_page_screenshot()` instead of `WebInterface.capture_page_screenshot(self)`.